# Where is Tween in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

It seems `mx.transitions.Tween` has be replaced in AS3 as I get a compiler error.

Does anyone know what is it replaced with or where is Tween moved?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/tweener/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Adobe AS3 docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html), it's `fl.transitions.Tween`.

<sub><sup>You really couldn't [Google that](http://www.google.com/search?&q=tween+as3) yourself?</sup></sub>

Comment: But the internal tweening engine is a filthy ***** so try googling Tweener or GTween. :)

Comment: @Ascension: thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, if the OP couldn't google "tween as3," what are the chances of them taking your advice? :\

Comment: Thanks @Ascension, this looks like a good resource. And others, I have like 4 days of flash experience. I found a few 'Graphics' examples and thought it has now changed to 'Graphics' class. But that was not true, hence the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to ActionScript. I'm using Flash Professional CS5. While I'm coding, when I enter the code like `new Tween=` it will import the header.

So there is Tween class in AS3 and its called `fl.transitions.Tween;`
You also need to import `fl.transitions.ease.*;` because the syntax of the Tween will use ease.

Answer (score 1):

I use tweenLite for my tweens. 
It's fast, reliable and easy to use.
such as:
`import com.greensock.*;
TweenLite.to(mc, 1, {x:65, y:117});`

You can find more information at http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the ans one package and your project should contain fla file....